# XNA Support Gestures on Windows 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-7, xna, multi-touch, gestures

One of my friends is working on a Windows phone 7 game and XNA allow you to support gestures, now he wants to use the same code so the game will be supported on PC (Windows 7) i want to know how i support gestures on PC with a Touch Screen monitor,   i have been looking on the web but apparently this is not so common.

So far the only reference that i have is to recreate the Touch class on C++, that's is not an option on time and budget

Maybe i am missing something obvious please help.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: they re do the game using a Engine, i know is not the answer but we never find it and the C++ class take to much time, if you need i can find you the name of the engine.

Answer (score 0):

What I know is that a touch screen monitor needs to be handled as a mouse, so your friend needs to change all his `gestures` with `MouseState` and detecting left button clicks.
You just need to replace `TouchLocations` with the location of the pointer.